# How do I pronounce 'toml'

Tags: pronunciation

I am wondering how to pronounce a toml file as it is a title. yaml is [zæ: mɛl] and I think the pronunciation is similar.

Comment: Where did you get that "word"? Please provide a link if available. Similarity of written letters does not guarantee a similarity in pronunciation.

Comment: @virolino That's a thing in programming.

Comment: Note that there often [isn't a single canonical pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/484750) of a made-up word. I have heard *SATA* pronounced at last three different ways by people in my own company, and there is famously no consensus on *GIF* or *SQL*.

Comment: I have never heard yaml as  [zæ: mɛl]. I pronounce it  /'jæməl/, and I've never heard anything else.

Comment: If it is a file type name, saying the characters as a word where possible is a common way of doing things, as in gif being /gɪf/ or /ʒɪf/, however, the default I suppose and in my opinion least errable way is to simply call the letters, i.e "dot tee-oh-em-el", "dot gee-ai-ef", "dot pee-en-gee" etc. It's pretty much just a good fallback if you don't know the standard pronunciation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's prounounced:

> tom-el

So "**tom**" (like the name) pronounced as usual, and then a letter "**l**", pronounced like "**el**" (as in "elephant").

So "tomel" it is.

You can see it [here](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/447) as well.

It's something like:

> [ˈtɒm.əl]